# Eclipse Ganymede javascript editor uses huge memory

Tags: javascript, eclipse, memory, memory-management, editor

I am new to here, but I wish someone can help me resolve the problem:

version: 3.5
OS: Win 7 64bit
JVM 1.6

I am using the javascript editor to write some code using YUI package, and seems it uses extremely huge amount of memory. Even when I put the mouse cursor on a variable, it will put up about 100M, so it runs to 1G very soon...

I tried to disable the javascript syntax validator, but seems I might only change the config file  tag to really disable it...

I use eclipse 3.2/3.3 on another machine (Win XP), which runs well...

Please advice what happens and what should I do.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems to me you're running into a memory leak issue with 64 bit Windows + Ganymede. Have you tried the Eclipse community yet? They have excellent support and love (good, reproducible) bug reports. PS: welcome at SO!

Comment: How do you check the memory consumption of your Eclipse process ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your prompt response.

I will try ask the eclipse community today.

I can see the memory heap runs up when I use the javascript editor, it can return to around 150M if I clear the memory (gc), but I have to do so every 2 minutes

Don't know how to become a member yet, let me figure out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you did and now it seems to me that the solution on this page has solved my problem: http://www.ithoughts.de/eclipse-out-of-memory-error-and-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

I actually set these values in my eclipse.ini:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

It takes only a minute to set these values and restart eclipse, I think it's at least worth a try.